# How to parse error response to Throwable?

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit, response, rx-java2

I am using `Retrofit` and `RxJava` to make network requests like this:

How I am declaring request:

```
@POST("auth/profile/edit/")
fun updateProfile(@Body body: ProfileUpdateBody): Single<Response<Void>>
```

How I am calling:

```
api.updateProfile(**some data**)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .doOnSubscribe {
          Log.d("----------", "Subscribed!")
     }
     .doOnSuccess {
          if(it.isSuccessful)
              Log.d("----------", "Success!")
          else
              Log.d("----------", "Not Successfull!")
     }
    .doOnError {
          Log.d("----------", "Error Happened!")
            }
    .subscribe({
     }, {

     })
```

Some code have been dropped for readability. The probem is even though I get responses back with 401 or 400 statuses, `doOnSuccess` is being called. Should not the `doOnError` be called here? I am confused.

As a result my logact is showing "Not Successful" message. How can make sure that `doOnErro` is called when I get responses back with 401 or 400 statuses?

Or can I parse the incoming response to `Throwable` and call `doOnError()` function?

Comment: Have you tried simply `: Completable` as the method return type?

Comment: @akarnokd no I have not. Should I?

Comment: If I use `Completable`, how to determine if the response was succesful or not?

Comment: `Completable` has two outcome: completes or fails. So `doOnComplete` instead of `doOnSuccess`.

Comment: Completable is likely not the right operator for an api request, we're probably interested in the response from the request, not just whether or not the request completed.
Single is better choice here.

Comment: The OP has `Response<Void>` thus no inner value. `Single<Void>` doesn't work so what's left is `Completable`.

Comment: @akarnokd What if the response (when everything goes as expected) from the server is empty response with 201 code? How to use `Completable` in this case? I have tried but when I recieve empty response with 201 code, `doOnError` is being called.

Comment: It should not. What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @akarnokd I am not getting any exceptions. When I receieve successful response from server with code 201 and empty body, for some wierd reason `doOnError` method is being called.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting *in `doOnError`* then?

Comment: @akarnokd my bad, it worked. I have just realized that I had `: Single<Completable>` instead of `:Completable`. That was the issue. Very wierd, behavior though when you have `: Single<Completable>`. Please write an anwer which shows your suggestions so that I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Retrofit API call to return `Completable`:

```
@POST("auth/profile/edit/")
fun updateProfile(@Body body: ProfileUpdateBody): Completable
```

then handle the "success case" via `doOnComplete`:

```
api.updateProfile(**some data**)
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .doOnSubscribe {
      Log.d("----------", "Subscribed!")
 }
 .doOnComplete {
      Log.d("----------", "Success!")
 }
 .doOnError {
      Log.d("----------", "Error Happened!")
 }
 .subscribe({  }, {  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The real question is, *why would you want to throw and exception when the request fails?*

The correct processes are being followed here, `doOnSuccess` is being called as intended because the request has returned a response without encountering an exception being thrown. Regardless of whether the request's response is successful or not.

You should handle the state of your response accordingly and not throw **arbitrary** exceptions for it:

```
api.updateProfile(**some data**)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(response -> {
         if (response.isSuccessful()) {
             // handle success
         } else {
             // handle failure
         }
     }, t -> {
         // handle thrown error
         yourErrorHandlerMethod(t);
     })
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i really need to work with `Throwable` since my logic very complex and dependant on `Throwable`s.

Comment: so throw when the response is a failure. The RX chain will not throw for you on a failed http response.

Answer (score 0):

The response you getting is correct, the response is shown in doOnSuccess cuz the `API` you hitting got successfully hit, no matter what was the response code.
doOnError is called when actual `API` call is failed like network drop in the middle or some server-side issues.

> Or can I parse the incoming response to Throwable and call doOnError() function?

You cant do this instead, you can handle the response in doOnSuccess as

```
 try {
 api.updateProfile(**some data**)
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .doOnSubscribe {
      Log.d("----------", "Subscribed!")
 }
 .doOnSuccess {
      if(it.isSuccessful) // responce code = 200/201
          Log.d("----------", "Success!")
      else if (it.responseCode == 400 ){
          Log.d("----------", "Not Found!")
          // Call a method that handles this according to your requirement.
          PageNotFoundHandler();
          // OPTIONAL throw new UserException();
        }
      else if (it.responseCode == 401 ){
          Log.d("----------", "Not Authorised!")
          // Call a method that handles this according to your requirement.
          TokenExpiredHandler(); //OR
          UnAuthorizedAccessHandler();
          // OPTIONAL throw new UserException();
        }
      else {
          Log.d("----------", "Some another Error!")
          // Call a method that handles this according to your requirement.
          // OPTIONAL throw new UserException();
        }

 }
.doOnError {
      Log.d("----------", "Error Happened!")
        }
.subscribe({
 }, {

 })
 } catch 
 {
    ErrorHandler();
 }
```

> Or can I parse the incoming response to Throwable and call doOnError() function?

As you mention that you want a throwable, you can achieve it by using the `try-catch` block.

Just throw a custom `EXCEPTION`, you have to create a new Custom Exception class for it.